# Nullpointerexception when trying to get data from bundle which is not null

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, parcelable

I'm facing a litte problem.

I'm trying to pass an playlist object to my media player service.

In its `onStartCommand`, I'm getting a `Nullpointer Exception` when trying to call `extras.get()` or `extras.getParcelable()`.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    L.d(this, "Service started");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();//Not null
    if (extras == null) {
        stopSelf();
        return 0;
    }
    L.d(this, "Extras was " + (extras == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    defaultPlaylist = extras.getParcelable("playlist");//Nullpointer
    currentSongNumber = extras.getInt(INITIAL_SONG_NUMBER);//Nullpointer

    registerReceiver(getApplicationContext());
    new NotificationPlayerControl(getApplicationContext());
    NotificationPlayerControl.update(defaultPlaylist.getSong(currentSongNumber));
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

`extras` is not null.

What is going on there?

Edit:
it seems that the error occures when I´m trying to write my parcelable object to the Bundle. I excluded it and now it runs well.

Maybe the Stacktrace was just a bit misleading

Comment: Have you tried directly calling `intent.getParcelableExtra("playlist")`?

Comment: yes,still the same problem. I also tried getInt which doesn´t work neither

Comment: Okay, it's possible that `playlist` is an incorrectly spelt key. Check if both the key when you pass the object and when you recieve it in your Service are the same. If no mapping of the type for the key exists, then it will return null.

Comment: But it should not crash the app with a nullpointer exception

Comment: Oh right... I'm not quite sure why you're getting a npe.

Comment: I just tried using different keys for when you're passing the Parcelable through an intent and when you're taking it out. A NullPointerException **was** thrown. Make sure your keys are the same (the case matters).

Comment: Can you post the exact changed code that fixed it?

Comment: No. I havent fixed it yet, sorry. There is something wrong with my Parcelable.Creator

Answer (score 0):

you are checking, but still accessing it after the check:

```
if (extras == null || defaultPlaylist == null) {
        stopSelf();
        return;
 } 
    L.d(this,"Extras was "+(extras==null?"null":"not null"));
   extras.getParcelable("playlist");
```

Comment: then that line does not throw a NPE

Comment: this is what it actually does and why I´m here. Tried your additional line. It´s not called and the nullpointer persists

Comment: what do you like to see?

Comment: Can you comment the last three lines out (not the return statement) and run it again?